# What is the probability of $B^2\ge 4AC$ if A, B and C are independent exponential random variables with parameter 1?

Tags: integration, exponential-distribution

I tried the following integral, is it correct?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}e^{-b}e^{-a}e^{-c}\,dc\,da\,db$$

Comment: I edited your post a bit to hopefully make it better match your actual intention. If that is not correct, please edit it to match.

Comment: Same; I presume the $b^2/4a$ was supposed to be a limit of integration (similar to the other one) rather than a factor in the integration itself.

Comment: Also, this integral is incorrect, and there's a relatively straightforward way of knowing that it _must_ be: as written, the formula has $c$ as a free variable, because of the middle integral (which is with respect to $a$ but has an upper limit of $b^2/4c$ with no subsequent integration over $c$ to remove the term in $c$ from the ultimate result). You need to take a little more care in delineating the area of integration.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you. It is correct.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you.

Comment: One possible hint: note that once you've 'fixed' some $b\in(0,\infty)$, the set of $a$ for which there's _some_ $c$ with $b^2\geq 4ac$ is still $(0,\infty)$ as well. In fact, you should be able to choose any order of integration you want, and only need appropriately 'dependent' limits on the innermost integration.

Comment: The integral is $1/3$ as it is written now

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach (but please double-check my calculations): fix $A,\,C$ so$$P(B\ge2\sqrt{AC})=\exp(-2\sqrt{AC}).$$With $a=s\cos^4\theta,\,b=s\sin^4\theta$, averaging gives$$\begin{align}\int_{[0,\,\infty)^2}\exp(-(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c})^2)dadc&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^3\theta\sin^3\theta d\theta\int_0^\infty s\exp(-s)ds\\&=4\frac{1}{12}1\\&=\frac13\end{align}$$by Beta and Gamma functions. [Python agrees with me](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/WittyDimgreyBooleanvalue).

Comment: Thank you. This solution is difficult for me. I tried to solve the integral in another way,  but I could not calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}-a}\,da$. Could you please help me with this? My solution is as follows:$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-b}e^{-a}(-e^{-c}|_{0}^{\frac{b^2}{4a}})\,da\,db=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-b}e^{-a}(1-e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}})\,da\,db=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-b}[\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}-a}\,da\,+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a}\,da]db$

Comment: @Rose Since $\int_0^\infty\exp(-x-k/x)dx=2\sqrt{k}K_1(2\sqrt{k})$ for $k>0$, your calculation continues as $1-\int_0^\infty bK_1(b)e^{-b}db=1-\frac23=\frac13$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-x-k%2Fx%29+from+0+to+infinity&dataset=) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*exp%28-x%29*K_1%28x%29+from+0+to+infinity).